# How to prove that $\wp''$'s zeros are not at half-periods?

Tags: number-theory, derivatives, roots, elliptic-functions

This is an exercise adapted from Apostol. The problem is stated as

> Prove that
>   $$\wp''\left(\frac{\omega_1}{2}\right)=2(e_1-e_2)(e_1-e_3)$$
>   where $\omega_1,\omega_2$ generates the lattice for $\wp$.

I could see that by Weierstrass' differential equation, we have
$$2\wp''\wp'=4\wp'((\wp-e_1)(\wp-e_2)+(\wp-e_2)(\wp-e_3)+(\wp-e_3)(\wp-e_1))$$
and
$$2\wp'''\wp'+2\wp''^2=4\wp''(\cdots)+4\wp'(\cdots)$$
At $z=\frac{\omega_1}{2}$ we have $\wp'''=\wp'=0$ since they are odd elliptic functions. Therefore,
$$2\wp''^2\left(\frac{\omega_1}{2}\right)=4(e_1-e_2)(e_1-e_3)\wp''$$

---

Now if $\wp''\left(\frac{\omega_1}{2}\right)\neq0$ we are done. However, I find it very difficult to prove the claim. I tried the following steps: first, we assume $\wp'(z)\neq 0$. Then by the expanded differential equation,
$$\wp''=6\wp^2-\frac{1}{2}g_2=6\left(\wp-\sqrt{\frac{g_2}{12}}\right)\left(\wp+\sqrt{\frac{g_2}{12}}\right)$$
Since $\wp(z)\pm\sqrt{\frac{g_2}{12}}$ are double zeros of $\wp''$ and the order of $\wp''$ is $4$, if I could prove that $\pm\sqrt{\frac{g_2}{12}}\neq e_i$, $i=1,2,3$ then we are done.

I tried to use the fact that $g_2=2(e_1^2+e_2^2+e_3^2)$, but it left me with the problem of proving
$$\frac{e_1^2+e_2^2+e_3^2}{6}\neq e_i^2$$
for all $i$.

**How can I proceed? or is there a simpler argument that applies? I must have missed something. Please help me. Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple argument is counting the multiplicities of values. $\wp'$ is an odd elliptic function with a single pole of order $3$, hence it attains each value in $\widehat{\mathbb{C}} = \mathbb{C}\cup \{\infty\}$ exactly three times (in a fundamental region) counting multiplicities. Now by oddness, we have
$$\wp'\biggl(\frac{\omega_1}{2}\biggr) = \wp'\biggl(\frac{\omega_2}{2}\biggr) = \wp'\biggl(\frac{\omega_1 + \omega_2}{2}\biggr) = 0\,,$$
hence these are all simple zeros of $\wp'$. In other words, $\wp''$ doesn't vanish at the half-periods.

Comment: If I am getting this correctly since $\wp'$ has zeros of order 1 at these half-periods, $\wp''$ would have zeros of order $1-1$ at these periods, which suggests it does not vanish. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. Although it's perhaps better to say this starting with $\wp''$. If $\wp''(\omega_1/2)$ were $0$, then $\wp'$ would have a zero of order $\geqslant 2$ there. Thus altogether $\wp'$ would attain the value $0$ at least four times (counting multiplicities), contradicting the fact that it's an elliptic function of order $3$.

Comment: Thank you. That is very clear.